# What are the x.x.x-rc Node.js versions in nodenv?

Tags: javascript, node.js, version, environment

After installing [nodenv](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv) and [node-build](https://github.com/nodenv/node-build) I viewed available Node.js versions `nodenv install --list`.

However, the list has several versions of the kind `6.11.0-rc.1`, `7.0.0-rc.1`, `7.0.0-rc.2` etc. along with their non-suffixed counter parts `6.11.0`, `7.0.0`

I haven't been able to find an explanation of what these **rc** versions are. Are they releases leading up to the complete Node.js versions or special files?

Comment: search for `software release cycle`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The acronym **rc** in the name of the version means **Release Candidate**. Usually, these versions are the previous version of the final release.

E.g. `7.0.0.-rc.1` is the previous version of the final release `7.0.0`. But, if  several mistakes are found in this release, then they make another **rc** before they make the final version. 
For this reason, you can also have `7.0.0-rc.2`and finally `7.0.0`. 

**rc** is like the step after a beta release.